# Is there a database of radio-frequencies for airfields/airports in Europe?

Tags: airport, radio-communications, easa-regulations, visual-flight-rules, datasets

Is there something like a register of frequencies for airfields/airports in Europe? I am building a VFR flight planner and would be interested to autofill a form with the frequencies dependent on the given input data. Is there something like a database?

Comment: As far as I know, something like that doesn't exist. You would also face a lot of problems trying to auto detect which frequency to use, because local procedures are very different. Flying to an airport with 5 tower frequencies, how would you know which one to use?

Comment: Just my two cents: FlightAware has tons of data, and I know they list frequencies for airports. I cannot confirm Europe specifically, but it is worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadcms/eadsite/index.php.html . It is not a database but you have access to all AIPs from members of Eurocontrol .

Comment: The problem with this is that all you get is a huge list of PDF files. Each country has a slightly different format, and some of the PDF's are just scanned documents! Importing this into a database which could be used by an automated application would be a huge manual task, let alone keeping that database up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For Germany I found a list of frequencies at *[Spitz Online](http://www.spitz-online.de/funkfram.htm)* (a private site of an enthusiast).

Excerpt:

[image]

It covers almost 700 <s>airfields</s> frequencies but I'm not sure how accurate it is.
For instance, I checked FRA/EDDF against [OurAirports](http://ourairports.com/airports/EDDF/pilot-info.html#comm) and noticed some differences.
He also lists different frequencies for the different purposes (APP, TWR, GND, ...), e.g. MUC/EDDM is listed with 33 (!) frequencies.

<s>But – as a programmer – you might be able to parse the output of [OurAirports](http://ourairports.com/airports/EDDF/pilot-info.html#comm). As far as I can see, the
URL is `http://ourairports.com/airports/<ICAO_CODE>/pilot-info.html#comm` and the returned HTML page
lists the frequencies in `<section id="comm" class="tab-pane fade">`. But you would have to parse
that yourself and I'm not sure whether they would really like that.</s>

#### Update

I again visited OurAirports and found their [data downloads](http://ourairports.com/data/) page. It's accessible from the menu. They say:

> For more intense work, we have a CSV-formatted data dump of all our airports, countries, and regions, which we update every night. You can download these files […] You can even use them to set up your own, competing airport web site if you'd like! We'd love you to give us credit, like we give credit to our sources, but you're not required to.

Right now the files have zero size (already indicated on that page) but when I looked yesterday they were all good and had reasonable sizes. The .csv with the frequencies had ~1.5 MB IIRC. So if you *trust* them, you could fetch the information from there. No need to crawl and parse their website. Note that this is not an “official” source but merely like a wiki where anybody who's signed-in can add and change DB entries.

Comment: This does not appear to be a reliable source, and as such should not be used operationally. Furthermore, since they offer no form of API, it would seem they are not interested in people simply crawling data from their site.

Comment: @J.Hougaard I totally agree and would not rely on this data but for the purpose of pre-filling a form in an app it may be a way to start with. Btw: OurAirports might not have an API but they – at least used to – [offer their data for download](http://ourairports.com/data/). As of today all the files are empty. I don't know if that's a temporary problem or whether they stopped that service. But they do offer their airport data: http://ourairports.com/world.html → Data → [airports.csv](http://ourairports.com/airports.csv). It doesn't include frequencies, though.